# perl script to retrieve some rows information from a csv file

Tags: perl, csv

I have a CSV file with 10 columns. The 8th column will have 0's and 1's. My script should check the 8th column for 1. If 1 is present in the 8th column it should print its corresponding 2nd and 10th column. I tried this but not properly working.

```
open PROJ3, "> proj3.h " or die $!;
open (CSV_XS, "<",$file ) or die $!;
while (<CSV_XS>) {
    if ($csv->parse($_)) {
        my @columns = $csv->fields();
        if($ARGV[1] eq "USPC") {
            if($columns[8]==1) {//checking is done here
                print PROJ ("ICU_VECTOR_INFO($columns[2] $columns[10])\n");
            }
        }
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us your input and output files, or parts thereof.

Comment: Is $csv declared as a suitable parser? Then use the perl debugger with perl -d and have a look at the variables in @columns.

Comment: Define "not properly working." Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });
```

to the top to declare your parser. If this package is not available at your system try to replace $csv->parse with a reg-exp.

Comment: The default `sep_char` is a comma, so you don't need to specify it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you said that there are 10 columns you meant 10 as number or as index? If you meant number, you should correct indexes of checked fields: `$columns[7]` instead of `$columns[8]`.